# How can I compare two array lists for equality with a custom comparator?

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparison

To be specific, I have two lists:

```
List<SystemUserWithNameAndId> list1;
List<SystemUserWithNameAndId> list2;
```

I want to check if they contain the same system users and ordering is not an issue. I tried to use a comparator to sort them first and then check if they're equal using the equals() method of lists. But I don't want to override the equals method for SystemUserWithNameAndId and I was wondering if I could use the comparator I created for sorting or a similar one to check for equality without explicitly iterating through the lists after sorting.

```
Comparator<SystemUserWithNameAndId> systemUserComparator = new Comparator<SystemUserWithNameAndId>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(SystemUserWithNameAndId systemUser1, SystemUserWithNameAndId systemUser2)
        {
            final int systemUserId1 = systemUser1.getSystemUserId();
            final int systemUserId2 = systemUser2.getSystemUserId();

            return systemUserId1 == systemUserId2 
                    ? 0
                    : systemUserId1 - systemUserId2;
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(systemUsers1, systemUserComparator);
    Collections.sort(systemUsers2, systemUserComparator);

    return systemUsers1.equals(systemUsers2);
```

Ideally, I want to be able to say,

```
CollectionUtils.isEqualCollections(systemUsers1, systemUsers2, someCustomComparator);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to override `SystemUserWithNameAndId.equals()`? Have you already overridden it?

Comment: Or you could do a SystemUsersList that extends List and override equals, then you could call: list1.equals(list2);

Comment: The code I posted is part of a test class and the way I'm comparing two `SystemUserWithNameAndId` objects is not the default way of comparing them.

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @pbabcdefp If you can think of something clever in Java 8 go ahead and post it IMO. We are teaching/documenting the language (some say as a primary focus). I was thinking about Java 8 too but I haven't had a good idea yet.

Comment: @Radiodef I would answer but the question is not yet clear. Is the OP wanting to test whether the two lists contain the same elements according to the `Comparator` (as JBNizet has assumed), or is the `Comparator` just a means to testing whether the two lists contain the same elements with respect to `equals`? In the question, the OP sorts the lists using the `Comparator` and then tests if the lists are the same by comparing elements with `equals()`, which makes no sense.

Comment: @pbabcdefp The `SystemUserWithNameAndId ` class has many attributes and I wan't to compare two `List<SystemUserWithNameAndId >` for equality. The comparator I've written is merely to sort the lists as you've rightly pointed out and I'm looking for a way to determine whether the lists have the same set of values for each `SystemUserWithNameAndId ` now that the elements of the lists have the same cardinality. JBNizet has essentially said that there is no utility method to check equality based on a comparator and I was hoping there was some in-built way of doing what his function does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just implement the method that iterates, and reuse it every time you need it:

```
public static <T> boolean areEqualIgnoringOrder(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {

    // if not the same size, lists are not equal
    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    // create sorted copies to avoid modifying the original lists
    List<T> copy1 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    List<T> copy2 = new ArrayList<>(list2);

    Collections.sort(copy1, comparator);
    Collections.sort(copy2, comparator);

    // iterate through the elements and compare them one by one using
    // the provided comparator.
    Iterator<T> it1 = copy1.iterator();
    Iterator<T> it2 = copy2.iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        T t1 = it1.next();
        T t2 = it2.next();
        if (comparator.compare(t1, t2) != 0) {
            // as soon as a difference is found, stop looping
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: He said "*without explicitly iterating through the lists after sorting*" - but I don't have an idea how this could be achieved (maybe with storing the objects in a `Set` or so, but for this, not enough information was provided)

Comment: As soon as you've written this generic reusable method, you never "explicitely loop". You "implicitely loop" by calling the method. There's no way to compare elements of lists without looping. And since the JDK doesn't provide such a utility method, you need to write one.

Comment: @JBNizet This is precisely what I was hoping I could avoid but if you're sure that there is no utility function to do this, I will have to resort to what you've recommended.

Comment: you have to iterate over the largest set, otherwise the areEqualIgnoringOrder will give bad results. Example: List a = [1,2,3], List b = [1,2,3,4]. areEqualIgnoringOrder(a,b, comparator) will return true.

Comment: @TomasBartalos the first thing the method does is to compare the sizes of the lists, which must be equal.

Comment: True, sorry for misleading comment, I've overlooked it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Java 8 way of solving your problem. First make sure the lists are of equal length:

```
List<SystemUserWithNameAndId> list1 = ... ;
List<SystemUserWithNameAndId> list2 = ... ;

if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
    return false;
}
```

Now build a Comparator using the new comparator utilities. The idea is that instead of writing custom logic for a comparator, most comparators do something like comparing two objects by extracting a key from them, and then comparing the keys. That's what this does.

```
Comparator<SystemUserWithNameAndId> comp =
    Comparator.comparingInt(SystemUserWithNameAndId::getSystemUserId);
```

Sort the lists. Of course, you might want to make copies before sorting if you don't want your function to have the side effect of sorting its input. If your input lists aren't random access (who uses `LinkedList` nowadays?) you might also want to copy them to `ArrayList`s to facilitate random access.

```
list1.sort(comp);
list2.sort(comp);
```

Run a stream over the indexes of the lists, calling the comparator on each pair. The comparator returns 0 if the elements are equals according to this comparator. If this is true for all pairs of elements, the lists are equal.

```
return IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .allMatch(i -> comp.compare(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)) == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm not using Java 8 yet but I will keep this in mind when I do make the switch. One minor caveat, I would  like to use different comparators for sorting and checking for equality as the criteria aren't the same.

Comment: @BruceWayne No problem. You can easily use `equals` or a different comparator in the predicate passed to `allMatch`.

Comment: Er... Although the question was about comparator, why not just use a predicator if just equality check is needed?